# htaccess which removes www and ensures https for multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, multiple-domains, no-www

I'm trying to setup my htaccess file to accomplish the 2 following things:

It needs to remove the www. from any domain
It needs to make sure that all domains use https

Right now this file controls 3 domains, but it could easily be dozens in the future, so it needs to be scalable

I found this solution in another post

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I get the following error in Safari: Too many redirects occurred trying to open “https://example.co/”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page.

Also, in order to redirect all http traffic to https I had found the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But when I go to http://example.co it redirects to localhost.

Here is the full code in case something else is relevant!!

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/modules/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be great - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this - the code I have above actually was working once I restarted the web server. Not sure why that was necessary - but everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was not able to find a solution using rewrites in htaccess or sites-enabled.

Instead, I learned that Letsencrypt although they do not allow wildcards will provide certs that list multiple variants of the same domain.

When running certbot their tool for managing certificates simply add "-d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com" to the cert generation command for certbot and it will lead you through the generation of a single SSL certificate that deals with both the www and bare variants without trouble. In thinking about it it would seem one could use this method to produce a single cert for a variety of subdomains, though I do not know enough to say this with surety.

I found it impossible to get this to work by editing the htaccess files, etc. I believe for the reason given elsewhere, that to get to an .htaccess or sites-enabled conf file one has to pass through the requirement for SSL verification.

Having spent a few days wrestling with this one I was more than happy to work this out from the Letsencrypt website. Though in a few weeks or months I expect that Letsencrypt will be offering wildcard certs.